# Detecting DOM XSS attack

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

I am trying to create a detector in order to flag DOM-based XSS attacks. I am trying to understand how to detect if a change made to DOM is legitimate or not. Am looking for links with helpful information or a short tutorial to:

- create a dom-based xss attack
- Ways to identify whether a change made to dom is legitimate or illegitimate

Thanks

Comment: Uhm, I really don't think you can distinguish between legitimate changes and illegitimate changes, just write robust code

Comment: For now I understand that it may not be quite possible to distinguish legitimate changes from illegitimate changes. But, is there a way to know when a dom structure is changed? Meaning, say a new object is added/deleted/edited in a web page, is there a way to identify what change has been made to the dom structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using the [DOM Mutation events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events)...